# EntityType 'FollowerMenuItemMerchant' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Other people have asked this question and I checked to see if I was making the same errors, and it appears I am not, from what I can tell.

Here is my *FollowerMenuItemMerchant* class.

```
      public class FollowerMenuItemMerchant
{
    [key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int FollowerID { get; set; }


    [key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int MenuItemID { get; set; }


    [key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int MerchantID { get; set; }

    public virtual Follower Follower { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }
    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }

}
```

And here is the *Context* class:

```
     public class FlavorPingContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public FlavorPingContext() : base("name=FlavorPingContext")
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MerchantDetails> MerchantDetails { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Follower> Followers { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.FollowerMenuItemMerchant> FollowerMenuItemMerchants { get; set; }


     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
    // Primary keys
    builder.Entity<Follower>().HasKey(q => q.FollowerID);
    builder.Entity<MenuItem>().HasKey(q => q.MenuItemID);
    builder.Entity<Merchant>().HasKey(q => q.MerchantID);
    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>().HasKey(q => 
        new { 
            q.FollowerID, q.MenuItemID, q.MerchantID
        });

    // Relationships
    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Follower)
        .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.FollowerID);

    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.MenuItem)
        .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.MenuItemID);

    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Merchant)
    .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.MerchantID);
}


}
```

Can you see where there may be an error?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, I found it!  I used lower case "key", and not uppercase "Key"!  Doh!